# Qual método posso usar para as bordas de JButton não aparecem?

Tags: java, swing, gui

Acho que a pergunta já descreve tudo: Qual método posso usar para que as bordas de meu `JButton` sejam transparentes (não apareçam) em Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
seuJButton.setBorder(null);
seuJButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
```

#### Resultado:

[image: resultado]

#### Info:

- [**AbstractButton#setContentAreaFilled()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setContentAreaFilled%28boolean%29)
- [**JComponent#setBorder**()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBorder%28javax.swing.border.Border%29)